# Examine method metadata (i.e. arity, arg types, etc)

Tags: crystal-lang

In Crystal, is it possible to view metadata on a type's method at compile time? For example, to determine the number of arguments the method accepts, what the type restrictions on the arguments are, etc.

Looking through the API, the compiler's [`Def`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/Crystal/Macros/Def.html) and [`Arg`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/Crystal/Macros/Arg.html) macros have methods which supposedly return this meta information, but I can't see a way of accessing them. I suspect the meta information is only accessible by the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out how to do it. I was looking in the wrong place of the API. The [`Crystal::Macros::TypeNode`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.26.1/Crystal/Macros/TypeNode.html) has a `methods` macro which returns an array of method `Def` (which is how you can access them). It looks like the `TypeNode` class is the entry point to a lot of good macros.

Usage example

```
class Person
  def name(a)
    "John"
  end

  def test
    {{@type.methods.map(&.name).join(', ')}}
  end
end
```

Or

```
{{@type.methods.first.args.first.name}}
```

Simply returning the argument name posses an interesting problem, because, after the macro interpreter pastes it into the program, the compiler interprets the name as a variable (which makes sense).

But the *real* value happens in being able to see the type restrictions of the method arguments

```
class Public < Person
  def name(a : String)
    a
  end

  def max
    {{@type.methods.first.args.first.restriction}}
  end
end

Person.new.max # => String
```

Comment: Great, if this fits what you were looking for. But note that this is *not* runtime reflection. Macros are expanded at compile time so all the things you can get through your macros from `TypeNode` are fixed at that point.

Comment: @JohannesMüller my question doesn't ask about *runtime reflection*. I simply asked if it was possible to view method names at runtime. And it is.

Comment: This being said, I do appreciate the response.

Comment: Pardon me, but the very first sentence asks to "view metadata on an object's method at runtime". That explicitly describes runtime reflection. Your answer doesn't provide that because you can't just ask an object about I its method names.

Comment: In Java for example, you can so that with `var.class.getDeclaredMethods()`.

Comment: @JohannesMüller Knowing what my goal was, how would you phrase the question?

Comment: Maybe don't ask for runtime information on an object but compile time information on a type?

Answer (score 0):

> I suspect the meta information is only accessible by the compiler.

Exactly. Crystal does not have runtime reflection. You can do a lot with macros at compile time, but once it is compiled, type and method information is no longer available.

But, since everything in a program is known a compile time, you shouldn't really need runtime reflection.

Comment: This is incorrect. Turns out you can access the methods on a class by going through the `TypeNode`. Also, I take issue with ~"because the program is compiled, you shouldn't need runtime reflection." Technically, I don't even *need* the ability to multiply numbers in a language. I could just stick with addition (adding things again and again and again). Or in the case of this problem, I could use another language to analyze my crystal source, get the list of methods, and copy paste them into the crystal program. But thankfully, the crystal folks let me access the methods using the `TypeNode`.

Comment: My statement is indeed valid. But it seems you asked the wrong question (runtime reflection) when you actually just care about compile time reflection.